# Comparing two Tags across two different Branches

Tags: git, diff, patch

I am trying to find an example how to compare two tags in two different branches so I can generate patch file. Let's say I have two branches, Dev and Prod. Production has Rel-01 Tag and Dev has Rel-02 tag. In simplified terms, I would like to run something like:

```
git diff Dev/Rel-02 Prod/Rel-01 > dev.patch
```

and then switch to Prod branch and run

```
git apply dev.patch
```

I have found many references how to compare two commits or tags in the same branch or two different branches but not scenario how to compare two commits (Tags) across different branches. Checking out one of the branches and running git diff would work also but the problem remains - how to properly reference Tag on another branch.

Comment: What would be wrong with just using `git cherry-pick` here?  In all honesty, I have been working with Git for nearly 10 years, and the number of times I have had to apply a patch I can count on one hand.

Comment: I have provided some information below; the idea is to use patch files as a way to pass changes across multiple staging environments where every staging environment has its own branch. It is Salesforce project so a lot of metadata to pass from one environment to next. Idea is to use patch files to force development provide correct one as early as possible and eliminate merge errors when release is pushed higher up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of

```
git diff tag-1 tag-2
```

has nothing to do with any branches in your tree. Whether `tag-1` and `tag-2` are on the same branch, or not is irrelevant to the diff. You might as well delete all your branches and run that diff again with the same results.

*Where* you apply the patch of that diff may be the main point of your concern, I guess, but we don't know much about the specifics of your context so far. Maybe consider pointing to a specific problem with the patch applying part.

Comment: So tags are not namespaced by the branches? I thought that Tags namespace is relative to branch. If not then this is another aspect for me to consider.

Comment: It is used in Salesforce CI\CD where staging between multiple environments is used to push new release to Production (Dev -> Dev-Integration -> Test -> Integration Test -> Pre-Production -> Production). Every environment (Salesforce) has its own branch. Idea is : using patch files can push patch creation to development and if tested then deploying patches on higher level environments should be error free. Problem is that people do a lot of mistakes during the merge process when whole metadata package is pushed from one environment to next.

Comment: @PetrLazecky No, tags are namespaced across the whole repo, not specifically separated along branches.

Comment: One more question please - if I configure remote tracking branch with Tags from remote repo - these are referenced differenly, right? As these Tags are from different repo I assume Git needs to know how to differentiate commit objects for my repo and those that come from remote repo.